# Try to display image from html using excel vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

i am working in excel vba. i want to insert an image in html using excel vba. but it doesn't show the image.

```
PlyrName="Me"
PlyrPicLoc = "C:\EP\Player Image\asdf1234567894.jpg"

HTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>" & _
"<html>" & _
"<head>" & _
"<title>" & PlyrName & "'s Profile" & "</title>" & _
"</head>" & _
"<body>" & _
"<img src=" & PlyrPicLoc & " height='150' width='150'>" & _
"</body>" & _
"</html"> 

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") With objIE
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .Visible = True
    .Document.Write HTML End With
Set objIE = Nothing
```

**UPDATE LAST AUGSUST 22 2013**

guyz it's working if im going to use the original picture that came from the web or i made it from adobe/snip but the problem is if that picture is only copied from original one and save it to EP\Player Image Folder using this code. it's not displaying. maybe there's something wrong wtih my code on copying?

```
Private Sub cmdinsertpic_Click()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim objfl As Variant
Dim msg


Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Image Files", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp", 1
    .Title = "Choose Player's image"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
    .Show
        For Each objfl In .SelectedItems
            FilNam = objfl
            Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(objfl)
            'Picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDalog.Filename)
        Next objfl
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

    'THIS WILL COPY THE PICTURE TO EP\Player Image Folder
    NameFile = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Player Image\" & Trim(txtnewplayername.Value & txtnewmc.Value) & ".gif"
    Call SavePicture(Image1.Picture, NameFile)

Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

For example i copied that orignal picture and name it as **asdf1234567894.gif** and will save to EP\Player Image Folder

```
Private Sub LoadPic_Click()
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
PlyrPicLoc = "file:///C:/EP/Player%20Image/asdf1234567894.gif"
Const PlyrNames = "Me"
Dim FSObj As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim TStream As Scripting.TextStream

sPATH = "C:\EP\sample.html"
sURL = "C:/EP/sample.html"

shtml = "<body>" & _
"<title>" & PlyrNames & "'s Profile" & "</title>" & _
"<img src=" & Chr(34) & PlyrPicLoc & Chr(34) & " height='150' width='150'>" & _
"<body>" & _
"</body>" & _
"</html>"

Set FSObj = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set TStream = FSObj.CreateTextFile(sPATH, True)
TStream.WriteLine (shtml)
TStream.Close


Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Navigate sURL
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .Visible = True
End With

Set objIE = Nothing
Set FSObj = Nothing
Set TStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: TestC.html will contain the HTML code as a text file, it is overwritten each time the code is ran. I have tried copying and pasting your code and ran it succesfully without the automation error :( Could you run it again and find out which line is leading to the automation error? (click debug and see which line is highlighted).

Comment: I don't think it's your code for copying. I think when you copy the file it will be in the origonal format. I'm guessing adobe/snip are converting the image to a gif format. If you rightclick the picture and select properties it should describe the format the file is currently in. If for example it is JPG you will need to store the picture and load it into the webpage in the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have investigated the source code, I have tried modifying it, but nothing I did seemed to work. I tried copying it into a text file and saving as html and hey presto it worked. Unfortunately I don't know why. I have compared the source code for the text file and code generated by excel and they are identical, but for some reason opening a text file works and writing it using .document.write did not.

As a work around I have used a file scripting object to write a text file version of the source code and then got the internet explorer object to navigate to that. the code I used is shown below the only things you should need to change are the addresses of the image and the text file. You should not need to change the text file adress as the file scripting object should overwrite it.

To make it work you will need to add references to microsoft scripting runtime and microsoft internet controls.

```
Sub image()
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
PlyrPicLoc = "file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/All%20Users/Documents/My%20Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Water%20lilies.jpg"
Const PlyrName = "Me"
Dim FSObj As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim TStream As Scripting.TextStream

sPATH = "E:\My Documents\StackOverflow\TestC.html"
sURL = "E:/My Documents/StackOverflow/TestC.html"

shtml = "<body>" & _
"<title>" & PlyrName & "'s Profile" & "</title>" & _
"<img src=" & Chr(34) & PlyrPicLoc & Chr(34) & " height='150' width='150'>" & _
"<body>" & _
"</body>" & _
"</html>"

Set FSObj = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set TStream = FSObj.CreateTextFile(sPATH, True)
TStream.WriteLine (shtml)
TStream.Close


Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Navigate sURL
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .Visible = True
End With

Set objIE = Nothing
Set FSObj = Nothing
Set TStream = Nothing 



End Sub
```

Comment: sir thank you for your reply and the sample. but i cant make it to work. maybe you can guide me to this problem. thank you so much again. i paste my updated code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you look at the source of generated page you should see the " are missing around your img source.

Try changing

```
"<img src=" & PlyrPicLoc & " height='150' width='150'>"
```

to

```
 "<img src=" & Chr(34) & PlyrPicLoc &  Chr(34) & " height='150' width='150'>"
```

If that fails can you post your html source from generated page?

TESTED AND WORKING OK WITH PNG AND JPG AND IE9

```
PlyrName="Me"
PlyrPicLoc = "PATH TO PICTURE"

HTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>" & _
"<html>" & _
"<head>" & _
"<title>" & PlyrName & "'s Profile" & "</title>" & _
"</head>" & _
"<body>" & _
"<img src=" & PlyrPicLoc & " height='150' width='150'>" & _
"</body>" & _
"</html>" 

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
With objIE
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    .Visible = True
    .Document.Write HTML 
End With
Set objIE = Nothing
```

Comment: i tried to test that on insert *.gif image. yes it works but when i insert other file like jpg or png, it's not displaying.

Comment: Can you try generating the following html code? Your title tag is in the body, it should be in the <head><title>Your Title</title></head><body>Your Picture</body>